# Scraping for text between nondescript tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In some instances, my text is in between vague values and attributes that reappear multiple times throughout the file (*e.g. '' is used repetitively*).

**Ultimately, I want to pull out:  "Prev Close:" and "565.07"** and put that information into something like a string or list (*please make a recommendation*).

---

**Portion of relevant HTML source:**

```
<div class="yui-u first yfi-start-content"><div class="yfi_quote_summary"><div id="yfi_quote_summary_data" class="rtq_table"><table id="table1"><tr><th scope="row" width="48%">Prev Close:</th><td class="yfnc_tabledata1">565.07</td></tr>
```

---

**My code (Python 3.4.1):**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data) # data contains the HTML source

FirstTable_tag = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': '"yui-u first yfi-start-content"'})
# Should the keys (attributes) in the "findNextSibling parameters below be filled in or left empty???
next_FirstTable_tag = FirstTable_tag.findNextSibling('div', attrs={'class': '"yfi_quote_summary"'})     
next_next_FirstTable_tag = next_FirstTable_tag.findNextSibling('div', attrs={'id': '"yfi_quote_sumary_data"', 'class': '"rtq_table"'})
next_next_next_FirstTable_tag = next_next_FirstTable_tag.findNextSibling('table', attrs={'id': '"table1"'})
data = next_next_next_FirstTable_tag.get_text()

SelectSoup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print("SelectSoup:" + SelectSoup + "(should be:  Prev Close)")
```

---

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    next_FirstTable_tag = FirstTable_tag.findNextSibling          
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findNextSibling'
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
```

---

### EDIT

[Here is the initial and full source as requested](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1NmkFdZ2mx3MmtNNUxfdDJkWUk/edit?usp=sharing)

*Although I have moved on to using Yahoo's API which is clearly a better method, I am still trying to get the scrape running out of curiosity with the assistance of @scandinavian_*

**I updated my code above but I am still having the same error.**

---

### EDIT 2

This post will henceforth focus on the solution @scandinavian_ is assisting to develop:

```
import sys
import urllib.request
url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GOOG"
urlRunner = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = urlRunner.read()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

import re
tables = soup.findAll("table", id = re.compile('^table'))
result = {}
for table in tables:
    for th, td in zip(table.findAll("th"), table.findAll("td")):
        result[th.text] = td.text
print(result)
```

**RESULT:**

`{'52wk Range:': '502.80 - 604.83', 'Market Cap:': '381.04B', 'Next Earnings Date:': 'N/A', 'P/E (ttm):': '29.52', 'Avg Vol (3m):': '1,701,610', 'EPS (ttm):': '19.09', '1y Target Est:': 'N/A', 'Volume:': '561,384', 'Ask:': '563.98 x 100', 'Div & Yield:': 'N/A (N/A) ', 'Bid:': '563.56 x 100', 'Beta:': '1.144', 'Open:': '568.00', "Day's Range:": '562.53 - 569.77', 'Prev Close:': '566.37'}`

Comment: I assume it is the data here you want to scrape? http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GRPN

Comment: Something like that @scandinavian_

Comment: Without a more complete example of what you want to scrape, it is hard to help you. If it is just Yahoo Finance you want to scrape, you would be better off using their comprehensive API. https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/ It is very easy to use.

Comment: @scandinavian_ this is the highest tag level underneath the HTML tag itself. Albeit, there are multiple div tags, this is truly the only section of code applicable and the source itself is many pages long so I figured I would just post the section containing what I need and get right to the point.  Please let me know what else you need to help me (so far you have the applicable source and initial idea of how to do it along with exactly why it does not work).

Comment: Your discription of your problem is confusing. This wouldn't be an issue if you provided an appropriate sample of the data. There is no reason to hide what you are scraping, and it is not the way to get an answer. I have submitted an answer based on what I guess you want.

Comment: +1 for scandinavian_'s assessment that an API solution would be superior.  Also, check Yahoo's TOS to make sure you aren't breaking rules; I believe they're fairly restrictive about how financial data can be redistributed.

Comment: Thanks @ghoti - I was not planning on making any of this code or derivatives of the code public. If I wanted to do so in the future I would definitely make sure I have their consent, but it is a good point to bring up.  I decided to initially begin scraping because the target website did not have an API... it is good that Yahoo does though!

Comment: global data has no place being there, but that is not the problem. I copy pasted the script and ran it, and it worked. It might be that there are regional differences in how they serve the content. Could you please print(data) and put it in a pastebin for me to see.

Comment: Thank you so much @scandinavian_ I just have 2 more quick questions:  #1) What determines the order of the results?          #2) I believe the data is currently in a dictionary?  If I wanted to later reuse this data and plug certain data points into different functions, how should I do so... also, how can I reorganize the names and values and display them in a more presentable manner (e.g. a multi-line list where each line starts with the description, has a space and dash, and then displays the value)?  Once I have reorganized the result, should it be stored in a tuple or something else?

Comment: BTW, @scandinavian_ I would upvote your answers but I am really new and don't have enough points... since I am so new at programing, I can't really answer questions well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on what I thought you want, but it is impossible to say without a proper sample of data. I can't guess how it is structured. In your description it sounds like the data is irregular, which is impossible to see in your sample.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import izip

html = """<div class="yui-u first yfi-start-content">
    <div class="yfi_quote_summary">
        <div id="yfi_quote_summary_data" class="rtq_table">
            <table id="table1">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" width="48%">Target Point:</th>
                    <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">200.22</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" width="48%">Target Point:</th>
                    <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">200.22</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" width="48%">Target Point:</th>
                    <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">200.22</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>"""

bs = BeautifulSoup(html)

result = {}

ths = bs.findAll("th")
tds = bs.findAll("td")
elements = izip(ths, tds)

result = []

for x, y in elements:
    result.append((x.text, y.text))

print result
```

Edit:

Yahoo API solution, please consider using this instead:

```
import requests

URL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql"

query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("GOOG")'

params = {
    "q": query,
    "format": "json",
    "env": "store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys"
}

data = requests.get(URL, params=params).json()

print data['query']['results']['quote']['PreviousClose']
print data['query']['results']['quote']['Open']
```

This will print:

```
565.07
561.78
```

These are the avaliable data for a stock:

```
AfterHoursChangeRealtime
AnnualizedGain
Ask
AskRealtime
AverageDailyVolume
Bid
BidRealtime
BookValue
Change
Change_PercentChange
ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage
ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage
ChangeFromYearHigh
ChangeFromYearLow
ChangeinPercent
ChangePercentRealtime
ChangeRealtime
Commission
Currency
DaysHigh
DaysLow
DaysRange
DaysRangeRealtime
DaysValueChange
DaysValueChangeRealtime
DividendPayDate
DividendShare
DividendYield
EarningsShare
EBITDA
EPSEstimateCurrentYear
EPSEstimateNextQuarter
EPSEstimateNextYear
ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid
ExDividendDate
FiftydayMovingAverage
HighLimit
HoldingsGain
HoldingsGainPercent
HoldingsGainPercentRealtime
HoldingsGainRealtime
HoldingsValue
HoldingsValueRealtime
LastTradeDate
LastTradePriceOnly
LastTradeRealtimeWithTime
LastTradeTime
LastTradeWithTime
LowLimit
MarketCapitalization
MarketCapRealtime
MoreInfo
Name
Notes
OneyrTargetPrice
Open
OrderBookRealtime
PEGRatio
PERatio
PERatioRealtime
PercebtChangeFromYearHigh
PercentChange
PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage
PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage
PercentChangeFromYearLow
PreviousClose
PriceBook
PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear
PriceEPSEstimateNextYear
PricePaid
PriceSales
SharesOwned
ShortRatio
StockExchange
symbol
Symbol
TickerTrend
TradeDate
TwoHundreddayMovingAverage
Volume
YearHigh
YearLow
YearRange
```

Comment: I apologize for my poor sample and I was not trying to hide but instead to simplify... I will post the entire original sample for your reference.  Thank you for your answer (I will try to implement it in a minuite but have not done so yet)

Comment: I have edited my post with a yahoo API solution for your problem. When a public API is avaliable, it is almost always a bad idea to scrape instead.

Comment: Thank you @scandinavian_ ... I knew of it but since I just picked up Python as my first official language, I thought scraping would be a good project to get me going.  I will try to get this running soon and I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks again!

Comment: even though I have moved on to the API, is there any way that you could cure my curiosity and let me know how I would go about scraping the webpage taking into consideration the fact that your first solution was not specific enough due to the fact that 'th' and 'td' repeat throughout the source?  It would need to be much more specific like in my initial example (with big bug fixes)??? Please!!!

Comment: I have posted what you requested as a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2

url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GOOG"
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)

#Find the two tables which ID's start with "table".
tables = bs.findAll("table", id=re.compile('^table')) 

result = {}

#Iterate the tables.
for table in tables:
    #Iterate both th and td in order.
    for th, td in zip(table.findAll("th"), table.findAll("td")):
        result[th.text] = td.text

print result
```

- 1) What determines the order of the results? 
  Dictionaries doesn't retain order, so they are in random order. If you need order, you can use an OrderedDict or a list containing tuples. The data is scraped left column from top to bottom and then right column top to bottom.
- 2) I believe the data is currently in a dictionary? If I wanted to later reuse this data and plug certain data points into different functions, how should I do so... also, how can I reorganize the names and values and display them in a more presentable manner (e.g. a multi-line list where each line starts with the description, has a space and dash, and then displays the value)? Once I have reorganized the result, should it be stored in a tuple or something else?

-

```
for key, val in result.items():
    print key + " - " + val
```

As for ordering we are moving into basic programming questions, which you will have a better understanding of just by reading about the different containers in python.

Comment: This just prints out "{}" @scandinavian_

Comment: What URL are you scraping?

Comment: I have edited the answer, the only difference is that I download the page for you. It works 100% as intended, so the problem must be on your end. Tested with Python 2.7

Comment: I am still having the same error (I had been downloading the page beforehand)... would it have anything to do with the fact that I am running Python 3.4.1?

Comment: Works for me in Python 3.4, just changing the print statement and using urllib.request instead of urllib2. You are doing something wrong, check that beautifulsoup loads the html. print(bs)

Comment: I was doing the same thing but like I said, it just outputs {} ... BTW, did you see my update to the findNextSibling method?  I still receive the same error. (see my question formatted as a comment in the code)

Comment: I have tested on Windows and two of my linux servers, the code works flawlessly. Post the code that doesn't work.
The code with findNextSibling doesn't work for several reasons, the first being that FirstTable_tag doesn't contain anything. I wont be helping with that solution, as it is a bad way of using BeautifulSoup. If you insist on doing it that way, try your luck at creating a new question and make it clear that you only want one specific solution.

Comment: I'm not insisting on that method so I will post the code we are working on.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your two questions.

Comment: Also,  I don't believe it costs points to upvote, only downvotes.

Comment: but you need to have 15 reputation @scandinavian_

Comment: Ohh my bad, it's no big deal :)